# What is wrong with my use of "cin.get" here?

Tags: c++, arrays, get, char, typedef

My code here seems to compile as long as I comment out the cin.get line but I don't see how I've misused it. As a second question, once I figure out what I've done wrong there, will it work for me to use getlength to count the length of that string, then use prtintf to print the cstring of that length to the output file I'm planning on adding in? I'm not allowed to use strings btw.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

struct thisType
{
    char peiceOne[100];
    char peiceTwo[100];
    char peiceThree[100];
};

void requestData();

void storeData(char *charArray[]);

int main(){
    thisType tempStruct[100];

    requestData();

    return 0;

}

    void requestData(){
        cout << endl << "Please enter data as follows, without brackets: [peiceOne];"
            << "[peiceTwo];[peiceThree] " << endl;

    }

    void storeData(char *tempStruct[100]){
        //cin.get(tempStruct[0], 100, ";");
    }
```

Comment: Please consider using `std::string` and the extraction operator `operator>>` for reading from an `std::istream` in c++.

Comment: It's for a class and I'm not allowed to use strings but I'm allowed to use cstrings.

Comment: Why would you include `<string>` then? For your code only `<iostream>` is required. C strings don't need to be "included" they are built-in types. `<cstring>` includes stuff you only need for string manipulation.

Comment: I didn't know that, I'll get rid of it.

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway? What's your assignment?

Comment: The assignment is to prompt the person to enter three pieces of related info as many times as they want, save them in the computer's memory (eventually write them to a file from memory), use an array of one type of struct, and include at least four user-defined functions with arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cin.get()`, the third parameter is expected to be a `char`, but you are passing a string which is of type `const char*`.

You should put the delimiter in single quotes, that would resolve the error.